# Mapping data to Large dictionary eating up my ram

Tags: dictionary, python-3.6, ram

This would be a noted one . 
My data consists of few million records with fields like user agent , Ip addresses and so on consisting of 10 columns .Every time the unique strings are been mapped to integers before feeding into ML-Models for training and saved using pickle. The data is been passed incrementally and Dictionaries are been unpickled and used for the new data set mapping .
As the dictionary gets bulky , Im facing issues with RAM usage only at last 2 fields mentioned above.Could you suggest any alternative for this condition and why is there a spike though large memory is available.

Memory size - 64Gb
Input Dictionary is of the size 2GB
input file size around 5GB with lenght 32432769

Comment: change line 7 in your code to: show the code please :) and then in line 9: we will help you :)

Comment: with open(filename,'rb') as file:
        Dict=pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
    new_count = Dict_count[j]
    print("The count of the dict is: ",new_count)
    for i in range(len(X)):
        if X[i][j] not in Dict:
            Dict[X[i][j]] = new_count
            new_count += 1
        X[i][j] = Dict[X[i][j]]
    exec("%s = %a" % (x_columns[j],Dict))
    new_count_list.append(new_count)